# Tabela com numeração errada no Overleaf

Tags: latex, bibtex

Preciso construir uma tabela em um trabalho que estou fazendo no Overleaf, mas por algum motivo a tabela inicia a ser contada a partir da 0 e não da 1 como é padrão da norma ABNT. Não acho que seja problema na programação da tabela no Source, pois copiei e colei em outro modelo e o problema não aconteceu: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da tabela:

```
\begin{table}[h!]   
\centering
\Caption{\label{tab:modeloUNIVESP2016} Modelos}     
\UNIFORtab{}{
        \begin{tabular}{cp{4cm}p{4cm}}
            \toprule
            Modelos & Dados de entrada & Técnicas de PO \\
            \midrule \midrule
            Deterministico & Conhecido ou sob  o controle do tomador de decisão & Programação Linear, não linear, inteira, redes, combinatória, ...\\
            Estocástico & Desconhecido  ou incerto & Simulação, Teoria das filas, otimização robusta, ...\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }{
    \Fonte{UNIVESP, 2016}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Você está utilizando um modelo da sua Universidade? Qual é o link para este modelo no Overleaf?

Comment: Este é um problema do modelo que você está utilizando, abra uma issue no [github da Unifortex2](https://github.com/profbrunolopes/unifortex2). Mas pelo que vi o bug da numeração da tabela foi corrigido 2 meses atrás, veja o [novo repositório](https://github.com/profbrunolopes/unifortex2/commit/1c8f8f6d5388007654edd76dcd569f7070d6b402).

Answer (score -3):

Tente caption, com "C" minúsculo